# hiding threads from CreateTool32Help api

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, api

Is is possible that someone can hide his or her thread from the CreateTool32Help api? I want to know this because I'm building an anti-cheat program for a little game I made. I don't want to go into kernel mode so the only way I can stop intruders injecting threads into my process is by comparing the threads I created with those found in the snapshot.

Could there be ways to circumvent this measure? I've hooked NtSetInformationThread just in case.

Comment: Someone could [Detours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#Windows) some Windows API to make itself invisible.

Comment: I find it funny that somebody is asking SO for anti-cheat techniques, since most SO questions are about how to cheat at video games.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody is running code inside your process, then you've already lost. Once they're in your process, they can patch your code that tries to detect them!

Comment: They can only do that if they have thoroughly studied and reversed the code. I'm not allowing all threads to access functions that could lead to leaks: VirtualProtect & allocate are blocked to all threads but one. But to be sure such checks work until they are patched I need to know for sure if threads can hide or not.

Comment: From a security standpoint, you assume your attacker has fully reverse-engineered your code. Any function you call, they can patch. If you are willing to assume they have not fully reverse-engineered your code, then you need to establish the boundaries between what you will assume they can do and what you will assume they haven't figured out. If you assume that they can patch any OS API, then you're stuck.